# Editing Chart Labels on Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, telerik-charting

I am developing a mobile application and currently working with charts (ScatterSeries to be more precise). By default, Nativescript shows the X and Y coordinates of Labels (showLabels="true"). Instead of this, I would like to display something different (let's say High, Medium, Low, etc...). I have looked for a property within labelStyle and ScatterSeries that will allow me to change this; but cannot find it (not sure this is the right approach).

PS: I am using this as a work-around since I couldn't figure a way to add a text to a certain area of the chart. So, if someone knows how to add a text label on a specific set of coordinates that will also do it.

Appreciate your help!